# PHP Jquery time bandwidth

Tags: php, jquery

I'm new with Jquery and payed someone to developed a script for me. I notice when I add this script to my website my bandwidth jumps from 1mb's to 5mb's. I have a lot of users on so it leaves me to believe the Jquery part is refreshing to quickly. My question is what do I need to change so it will stop using so much bandwidth in the script below.

Thank you!

```
<script>

current_time = 1342987067;
start_at = 1342986987;
waiting_time = 120;
break_time = 9999;
view_1 = 'Text removed for example<br>';
view_2 = 'Text removed for example<b><span id="countdown-value"></span></b> seconds.<br>';
view_3 = 'Text removed for example... currently in progress...<br>';
winner = "Text removed for example";

function changeView() {
    if (start_at + waiting_time > current_time) {
        if (break_time < waiting_time) {
            return view_1 + "\n" + winner;
        } else {
            return view_2 + "\n" + winner;
        }
    } else {
        return view_3 + "\n" + winner;
    }
}

function setView() {
    $("#countdown-holder")[0].innerHTML = changeView();
}

function reload() {
    current_time ++;
    break_time = start_at + waiting_time - current_time;
    setView();
    if (break_time <= waiting_time) {
        if ($("#countdown-value")[0] != null)
            $("#countdown-value")[0].innerHTML = break_time;
    } else {
        if ($("#countdown-value")[0] != null)
            $("#countdown-value")[0].innerHTML = break_time - waiting_time;
    }
    setTimeout("reload()", 1000);
}
setTimeout("reload()", 1000);
setView();

</script>
<script>

function setBreakTimeCountdown() {

    breakTimeCountdown = parseInt($("#countdown-value")[0].innerHTML);

    breakTimeCountdown --;

    if (breakTimeCountdown < 0) {

        breakTimeCountdown = 0;

        reload();

    }

    $("#countdown-value")[0].innerHTML = breakTimeCountdown;

    setTimeout("setBreakTimeCountdown()", 1000);

}

setTimeout("setBreakTimeCountdown()", 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Did you remove the part that could take bandwidth? There is no network I/O in the code.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a thing in there that even causes a page-refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in the script seems to be calling back to your site, so I'm guessing it's loading jQuery itself that's the issue?

Easiest solution would be to use the [Google Libraries API](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide). Scroll down and get the jQuery link, and replace your local jQuery with that. It will use Google's bandwidth instead.

Answer (score 1):

None of the calls in that piece of javascript appear to be triggering any requests directly.

However, if any of the variables `view_1`, `view_2`, `view_3`, and `winner` were to contain HTML that has references to other media resources in them, that could trigger more requests to your server, which would increase bandwidth utilization.

Comment: setting `.innerHTML` doesn't load or execute scripts though